# How to access the TempData in the startup.cs file?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor, tempdata

I have a Middleware in the startup.cs file (Razor Pages) and want to check whether a value exists in the TempData, but I cannot find a way to access the TempData. Am I heading towards a bad practice? If so, how could I read a runtime-produced value in my Middleware?

Comment: What are you trying to do? What kind of value are you trying to access inside a middleware?

Comment: Please show us what you've done so far. BR

Comment: I store some values that are used throughout the app in the TempData. There are cases where TempData expires or are empty. I just want to see if there is a way to check the TempData outside of a Razor Page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use `ITempDataDictionaryFactory`,Here is a demo:

Middleware:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            app.Use(async (context, next) =>
            {
                ITempDataDictionaryFactory factory = context.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(ITempDataDictionaryFactory)) as ITempDataDictionaryFactory;
                ITempDataDictionary tempData = factory.GetTempData(context);
                //get or set data in tempData
                var TestData=tempData["TestData"];
                // Do work that doesn't write to the Response.
                await next.Invoke();
                // Do logging or other work that doesn't write to the Response.
            });
       }
```

HomeController:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            TempData["TestData"] = "test";
            return View();
        }

       
    }
```

result:
[image]

Comment: Can you accept it as an answer?Thank you.